# how to make mouse scroll compatible to all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a webpage which scrolls good in chrome but in firefox it doesn't work good.

Below is the link of that webpage 
https://chayenu.org/app2/

In this web page when you scroll down to "Explore The App
" section and there if you scroll up it works fine in chrome and scrolls up but not in firefox.

Comment: Works fine for me, in Firefox exactly as in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It works well in FireFox. May be you are using older version. Try to update browser.